# Entry to android programming

Tags: android

In the following program , when i try to run its getting error

```
textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGetInput);
```

in this line. Its showing error in tvGetInput. How can i fix it ?

```
package was.thebasics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class mymenu extends Activity {

    TextView textOut;
    EditText GetInput;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textOut = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGetInput);
        GetInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
        Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bOK);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                textOut.setText(GetInput.getText());
            }
        });
        // set up the button sound
        final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button);



        Button bTutorial1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tutorial1);
        bTutorial1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent("was.thebasics.tutorialOne"));
                mpButtonClick.start();
            }
        });


    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check in main.xml file Textview id is given like that that.

```
android:id="@+id/tvGetInput"
```

Comment: thank you brother.. i fixed.. if possible plz give some suggestion to understand easily the android basic concepts.. I know the different blocks used .. but i dont know why they are used..

Answer (score 1):

check that the id is created in R.java file,under gen folder

Comment: thank you brother.. i fixed.. if possible plz give some suggestion to understand easily the android basic concepts.. I know the different blocks used .. but i dont know why they are used..